# SQL: Is querying a `group_id` before an individual `id` better compared to the other way around?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Setup:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (group_id integer, id integer)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (1, 1)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (1, 2)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (1, 3)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (2, 1)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (2, 2)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (3, 1)
...
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (999, 999999)
```

Query #1

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE group_id > 1 AND group_id < 10 AND id > 100
```

Query #2

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id > 100 AND group_id > 1 AND group_id < 10
```

Is there any performance difference between query #1 vs query #2?

More specifically, is there any advantage or disadvantage querying a "lower resolution" column (eg `group_id`) before a "higher resolution" column (eg `id`)?

(Using Postgresql)

Comment: no ..the query are the same

Comment: You can check the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` result and I am pretty sure it will be the same

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the explain query you will find that the order of your where clauses has no impact on the query plan, execution, or performance.  From a PSQL standpoint your queries are functionally equivalent.